# Add Form View Helpers to View

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using ZF2's PhpRenderer as a standalone component in my app like this:

```
public function render(ViewModel $viewModel)
{
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer;
    $resolver = new Resolver\AggregateResolver();
    $stack = new Resolver\TemplatePathStack(array(
        'script_paths' => $this->viewFolders
    ));
    $resolver->attach($stack);
    $renderer->setResolver($resolver);

    return $renderer->render($viewModel);
}
```

Form View Helpers are under Zend\Form\View\Helper namespace and i need to use FormCollection view helper to render my form but how can i add this namespace to current view helpers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the HelperPluginManager to your Applications HelperPluginManager, so then it can find dependencies etc for you.

Using it manually like this will mean you don't have anything magically setup for you and you will need to add them in yourself.

```
$renderer = new PhpRenderer;
// where $sm is your servicelocator/manager
$renderer->setHelperPluginManager($sm->get('HelperPluginManager'));
$renderer->setServiceLocator($sm);
```